# using valid field breaks input box; knockoutJS

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

from http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections

Changing

```
<td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
```

to

```
<td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: name, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
```

causes the input box to break. When broken, the surcharge doesn't update when you change the meal, and the default meal name doesn't match the price (always first meal, sometimes second price)

```js
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];    

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[1]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
    ]);
    
    // Operations
    self.addSeat = function() {
        self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: name, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td> 
            <td data-bind="text: meal().price"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addSeat">Reserve another seat</button>
```

`name` is a valid field in the SeatReservation, and this for loop is iterating over seat reservations. Why doesn't it just show the person's name, why does it go to the default meal value? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem, as mentioned above, is that you are trying to assign the value from the dropdown into the name field (this is the portion that is written `value: name`).

If you wanted to show something different within the dropdown field, you would need to modify the **optionsText** property, similar to this:

```
<td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: name, optionsText: 'desiredPropertyNameGoesHere'"></select></td>
```

This is because the text that is rendered in the dropdown is pulled into the select by the `optionsText` property.  The `value` binding assigns a value to an observable.  The `text` binding displays a value from an observable.  I think what may be happening is that you are confusing the behavior of the `text` and `value` bindings.  When I first started, I made that mistake as well.

You can see that if you look at your `<input>` element, which is using the `value` accessor to pull the reservation's owner name into the field.

```
<td><input data-bind="value: name"></input></td>
```

If you were to do this with a different HTML element, such as `<span>`, you would need to use the following binding setup instead:

```
<td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
```

See [My Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTjol.jpg) to show the difference in the example you have been working on.

I hope that helps to clarify a little of what is going on with the example.

Answer (score 1):

`meal` is an observable, and value binding requires an observable to put the selected value in it, otherwise, nothing changes after selecting different values

Comment: I don't understand why it wouldn't display name though. Name isn't observable, it's a string

Answer (score 1):

Break down the bindings in the `<select>`:

- `options` takes an array to populate the drop down
- `optionsText` lets you specify a property of an item to display as the text
- `value` is where you *save* a selected value